# android sql appeding string data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to append string data like this

> name, id
>
> app, 1

to

> name, id
>
> appending, 1

but the code below outputs

V/name: 0

V/id: 1

Despite I updated my table to "name = name + 'ending' " It outputs 0... why?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("User", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (name VARCHAR(100), id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");

    String sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)";
    SQLiteStatement statement = sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.bindString(1, "app");
    statement.execute();

    String sql2 = "UPDATE test SET name = name + ? WHERE id = ?";
    statement = sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement(sql2);
    statement.bindString(1, "ending");
    statement.bindLong(2, 1);
    statement.execute();


    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM test", null);
    int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");

    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        Log.v("name", c.getString(nameIndex));
        Log.v("id", c.getString(idIndex));
    } while (c.moveToNext());

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM test");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string concatenation operator in SQLite is `||`, not `+`, so you should be using the following update query:

```
String sql2 = "UPDATE test SET name = name || ? WHERE id = ?";
```

Some other databases *do* use `+` for string concatenation (e.g. SQL Server); perhaps this is where your usage came from.